# Using return in Python

Tags: python

My aim is to be able use x in the corrosponding location
eg. if the reply was 1 then in location1 x should be 1 however if I use this code then x doesn't get returned until after that location is executed. However if the return command is executed first then the location is not executed due to the fact that return finishes the fuction.

```
def town():
    reply = input('What is your rely?')

    if reply == '1':
        x = 1
        location1()
        return x

    if reply == '2':
        x = 2 
        location2()
        return x

    if reply == '3':
        x = 3 
        location3()
        return x
```

Could someone please provide me with a solution, the simpler the better.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the return, it's you not using arguments. You can use location(x) to pass x to the location method. No need to return for that.

```
def town():
    reply = input('What is your rely?')
    if reply == '1':
        location1(reply)
    elif reply == '2':
        location2(reply)
    elif reply == '2':
        location3(reply)

def location1(argument):
   print("reply was " + argument)

def location2(x):
   print("reply was " + x)

def location3(argument):
   print("reply was " + argument)
```

Also a bit of code efficiency: On `town()` we pass the argument `reply` to the `location()` methods because we already checked that it's either "1", "2" or "3" (as per your `if`). No need to use a new variable called `x` and assign a value for it when your current `reply` already have that value.

Comment: Sorry for sounding ignorant but how do I use things like location(argument), btw I started python recently and don't have much experience with it

Comment: I added made-up location methods/functions so you could check. When you define a function you can add as many arguments as you will use inside its brackets (). So if you create a method as the next example: `def something(a, b, c)` then you can call it later using `something(1, "whatever", "this is an example")`.  An argument is something that you pass from one function to another. It can be a variable, a list, a class, etc.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send you a piece of my code and a question about it?

Comment: You can create a new question. This is what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Yeah my questions on Stack haven't been so good so they said no more questions for 4 days

Comment: I can see why. You are having issues with basic stuff that should be learnt before starting to program. I suggest you to check this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you the following solution, with comments for you to understand:

```
def town():
    reply = input('What is your reply? ')

    if reply in '123':
        # Here: the reply is '1', '2' or '3'
        x = int(reply)  # it converts the string into an integer
        location(x)     # it passes the integer as parameter to the function 'location'
        return x        # it returns the integer value
    else:
        # Here: the reply is different from '1', '2' or '3'
        print("Reply is different from '1', '2' or '3'")
        return None

def location(x):
    # Do something depending on the value of the input parameter x
    if x == 1:
        do_something_1()  # Implement what you want here
    elif x == 2:
        do_something_2()  # Implement what you want here
    else:
        do_something_3()  # Implement what you want here

town()
```